# Keycloak docker image not running any more Failed to start service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.ajp

Tags: docker, keycloak

i'm a new to keycloak, sorry for this newby post.
I have a docker image that was working perfectly, the same image is deployed on AWS and everything is working fine but suddenly the execution fails for this image locally and it doesn't want to be executed after a system reboot here are the logs if anyone had the same error:
KC version 8.2.0 Config:

```
{
      "KC_DOMAIN": "http://keycloak:8080",
      "KC_PRIVATE_DOMAIN": "http://keycloak:8080",

      "KC_LIFE_SPAN_DISTRIBUTOR": "1200",
      "KC_LIFE_SPAN_IMPLICIT_FLOW_DISTRIBUTOR": "1200",
      "KC_SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT_DISTRIBUTOR": "3600",
      "KC_SESSION_MAX_LIFE_SPAN_DISTRIBUTOR": "43200",
      "KC_XFRAME_OPTIONS_DISTRIBUTOR": "ALLOW ORIGIN *",
      "KC_CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY_DISTRIBUTOR": "frame-src 'self' *; frame-ancestors 'self' *; object-src 'none';",
      "KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL": "INFO",
      "EVENT_LOGLEVEL": "DEBUG",
      "ROOT_LOGLEVEL": "INFO",
      "JGROUP_LOGLEVEL": "INFO",
      "KEYCLOAK_LOG_ROTATE_SIZE":"10240k",
      "KEYCLOAK_LOG_MAX_BACKUP_INDEX":"50",
      "ENABLE_INFINISPAN_STATISTICS": "false",
      "DB_USER": "keycloak",
      "DB_PASSWORD": "******",
      "DB_ADDR": "mysql",
      "DB_PORT": "3306",
      "DB_DATABASE": "keycloak",
      "JDBC_PARAMS": "",
      "PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING": "false",
      "KC_SSL_REQUIRED": "none",
      "MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS": "25",
      "QUEUE_SIZE": "100"
}
```

Error when i execute the docker image:

```
 ...

     13:35:42,295 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 128 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
    13:35:42,366 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/opt/keycloak/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
    13:35:42,448 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
    13:35:42,486 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
    13:35:42,674 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.ajp: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.ajp: WFLYUT0082: Could not start 'ajp' listener.
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:211)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
            at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
            at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222)
            at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85)
            at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.java:178)
            at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:310)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.AjpListenerService.startListening(AjpListenerService.java:64)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:199)
            ... 8 more
    
    13:35:42,674 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default: WFLYUT0082: Could not start 'default' listener.
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:211)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
            at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
            at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222)
            at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85)
            at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.java:178)
            at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:310)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.HttpListenerService.startListening(HttpListenerService.java:106)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:199)
            ... 8 more
2021-11-19T13:35:43.686Z WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.keycloak-server.war" is using a private module ("org.kie") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
2021-11-19T13:35:45.327Z ERROR [org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JGRP000138: Error reading JDBC_PING table: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "JGROUPSPING" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT ping_data, own_addr, cluster_name FROM JGROUPSPING WHERE cluster_name=? [42102-193]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5389)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1257)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1897)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2045)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1891)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1709)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1697)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:445)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:317)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:254)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:561)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:502)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1203)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:676)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.doPrepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:758)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.prepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:744)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection$5.produce(WrappedConnection.java:516)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection$5.produce(WrappedConnection.java:514)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.SecurityActions.executeInTccl(SecurityActions.java:97)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:514)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING.prepareStatement(JDBC_PING.java:209)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING.readAll(JDBC_PING.java:221)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING.readAll(JDBC_PING.java:197)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FILE_PING.findMembers(FILE_PING.java:124)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.invokeFindMembers(Discovery.java:216)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.findMembers(Discovery.java:241)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.down(Discovery.java:380)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FILE_PING.down(FILE_PING.java:119)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE3.down(MERGE3.java:278)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.down(FD_SOCK.java:377)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FD.down(FD.java:320)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.down(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:102)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.down(NAKACK2.java:553)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.down(UNICAST3.java:581)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.down(STABLE.java:347)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.ClientGmsImpl.joinInternal(ClientGmsImpl.java:72)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.ClientGmsImpl.join(ClientGmsImpl.java:40)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.down(GMS.java:1044)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.down(FlowControl.java:295)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG3.down(FRAG3.java:135)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FORK.down(FORK.java:109)
        at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.down(ProtocolStack.java:928)
        at org.jgroups.JChannel.down(JChannel.java:627)
        at org.jgroups.JChannel._connect(JChannel.java:855)
        at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:352)
        at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:343)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.subsystem.ChannelServiceConfigurator.get(ChannelServiceConfigurator.java:112)        at org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.subsystem.ChannelServiceConfigurator.get(ChannelServiceConfigurator.java:58)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.service.FunctionalService.start(FunctionalService.java:67)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.service.AsyncServiceConfigurator$AsyncService.lambda$start$0(AsyncServiceConfigurator.java:117)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
        Suppressed: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "JGROUPSPING" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT ping_data, own_addr, cluster_name FROM JGROUPSPING WHERE cluster_name=? [42102-193]
                at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
                at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
                at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5389)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1257)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1897)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2045)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1891)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1709)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1697)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:445)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:317)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:254)
                at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:561)
                at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:502)
                at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1203)
                at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
                at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:676)
                at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.doPrepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:758)
                at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.prepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:744)
                at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection$4.produce(WrappedConnection.java:478)
                at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection$4.produce(WrappedConnection.java:476)
                at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.SecurityActions.executeInTccl(SecurityActions.java:97)
                at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:476)
                at org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING.prepareStatement(JDBC_PING.java:212)
                ... 35 more

2021-11-19T13:35:45.330Z ERROR [org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JGRP000145: Error updating JDBC_PING table: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "JGROUPSPING" not found; SQL statement:
DELETE FROM JGROUPSPING WHERE own_addr=? AND cluster_name=? [42102-193]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
...
```

Comment: You should to check the database config in the `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose` file and also the database health check.

Comment: Hi @vhthanh thanx for your reply, i update the env to add the JDBC_PARAMS to useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true but in the console i see that when i execute the docker image those changes are not taking into considiration

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was this error:

```
13:35:42,674 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.ajp: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.ajp: WFLYUT0082: Could not start 'ajp' listener.
```

This is a an error from the JBOSS application server (Wildfly) that failed to open a socket to listen for incoming connections due to attempting to open an IPv6 socket

And the solution that worked for me is that the JAVA_OPTS environment variable must be set to contain -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

And here is how i apply this to change keycloak jvm arguments via CLI in standalone configuration, i modify the commons.sh script which is executed in the standalone.sh by adding this enty:

```
if [[ "$JAVA_OPTS" != *"-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"* ]]; then
   export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
fi
```

You can find more informations in this [link](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/206185/could-not-start-wildfly-default-listener.html)